# Program to decide whether second number is a multiple of the first not working properly

Tags: java

This program should be returning True if the second number is a multiple of the first. False if it is not, and it should do it three times.
The output is just giving whatever answer is correct for the first one.
How can I get the return to include the variables f, and g?

Or if that is not the correct way to go about it what is? I need to have them all come from the same method, otherwise I'd just make more methods, but as it is I'm stumped.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry for my noobiness.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numbers3 {
    // starts execution of java application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int firstnumber = 0; // initialize integer first number
        int secondnumber = 0; // initialize integer second number
        int third = 0;
        int fourth = 0;
        int fifth = 0;
        int sixth = 0;

        // First input field
        System.out.print("Input first number ");
        firstnumber = input.nextInt();
        // Second input field
        System.out.print("Input second number ");
        secondnumber = input.nextInt();

        // makes result equal the Boolean output of isMultiple method
        Boolean result = isMultiple(firstnumber, secondnumber, third, fourth,
                fifth, sixth);

        System.out.println("" + result);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("input first number ");
        third = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("input second number ");
        fourth = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("" + result);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("input first number ");
        fifth = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("input second number ");
        sixth = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("" + result);
    }

    // creates method using the user input
    public static Boolean isMultiple(int a, int b, int w, int x, int y, int z) {

        Boolean e = null; // initialize boolean
        Boolean f = null;
        Boolean g = null;

        if (a % b != 0) // what the function does if the result is not 0
            e = false;

        // what the function will do if the function does result in 0
        if (a % b == 0)
            e = true;

        if (w % x != 0)
            f = false;

        if (w % x == 0)
            f = true;

        if (y % z != 0)
            g = false;

        if (y % z == 0)
            g = true;

        return e;

        // returns e as the result of this method.
    } // end program
} // end class
```

Comment: You can change the return type to a `Boolea[]` and use `return new Boolean[]{e, f, g}` to return all the results. Also you may want to use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`

Comment: What's with `f` and `g`? They don't seem to be of any use.

Comment: I've used Boolean instead of boolean so that I could initialize to null, is that a bad idea? thanks for the other thing though, that's very helpful.

Comment: It is not the best idea, but it certainly works. Also, use `if() {} else {}`.

Comment: @johnny is unnecessary since you need only a binary response, `true` or `false`.

Comment: whitespace is for readability, am I missing braces?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You're right. But, johnny isn't missing braces. For `if`, `while`, `else`, and `for` blocks, braces aren't necessary if there is only one line in the block.

Comment: @Titus I have converted everything to boolean[] but I'm getting the an error saying that boolean[] cannot be converted to boolean.
Do I need to change the values somehow?

Comment: @JamesSmith Sure looks like those `if`(s) are at varying levels of indentation to me... that's why I asked if it was intentional.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah... Well, since it's Java, it won't matter. It's bad code style, and I don't particularly like it, but it still does work. Tip: If you are using Eclipse, `Ctrl-Shift-F` will format the code properly. On OS X, it's `Cmd-Shift-F`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That is just so I could see things more easily, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Use `boolean[]` only on the return type `public static boolea[] isMultiple` and the `result`  `boolean[] result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every run, there's two inputs.
**Objective:** Check if the first input is a multiple of the second input using **`isMultiple()`**.

To run it 3 (or any #) times, put the *`repeating code`* in a for loop.
# of times to repeat the loop is stored in the constant **`NUM_RUNS`**.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numbers3 {

    private static final int NUM_RUNS = 3;

    // starts execution of java application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_RUNS; i++) {

            // First input field
            System.out.print("Input first number: ");
            int firstNumber = input.nextInt();
            // Second input field
            System.out.print("Input second number: ");
            int secondNumber = input.nextInt();

            System.out.printf("%d is a multiple of %d: %s%n%n",
                    firstNumber, secondNumber,
                    isMultiple(firstNumber, secondNumber));
        }
    }

    public static boolean isMultiple(int a, int b) {
        return (a % b == 0);
    }
} // end class
```

**Example Input/Output:**

```
Input first number: 8
Input second number: 2
8 is a multiple of 2: true

Input first number: 7
Input second number: 3
7 is a multiple of 3: false

Input first number: 18
Input second number: 6
18 is a multiple of 6: true
```

Comment: @ElliottFrisch My bad, should be boolean. Edited it from the OP's code.

Comment: Nice. Also, I'd suggest declaring the `int`(s) in the `for` body.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Are there any significant benefits to declaring the int(s), i.e. firstNumber & secondNumber within the for loop? I mean, I could do that, just that it seems the same to me?

Comment: Restricting variable visibility is a fairly basic OOP principle. Also, two less lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's with `f` and `g`, but here's a program that asks for two numbers, three times, and prints `true` or `false` if the second is a multiple of the first:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter first number : ");
        int first = Integer.parseInt(reader.
        System.out.print("Enter second number : ");
        int second = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        boolean secondMultipleOfFirst = second % first == 0;
        System.out.println(secondMultipleOfFirst);
    }
}
```

And I know what's wrong with your method, as well. You are calculating the values correctly, but every time you are returning `e`, which is the first result. So, the next two inputs give the first result.

Instead of setting up more methods, or a way to see which value to return, use a loop. That way, you take two values and see if `n2` is a multiple of `n1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dump_me;

import java.util.Scanner;

     public class Numbers3
    {
       // starts execution of java application
       public static void main( String[] args)
       {
           Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in );
           int firstnumber = 0; // initialize integer first number
           int secondnumber = 0; // initialize integer second number
    // makes result equal the Boolean output of isMultiple method
           String loop = "N";
           do{
   // First input field
           System.out.print("Input first number ");
           firstnumber = input.nextInt();
           // Second input field
           System.out.print("Input second number ");
           secondnumber = input.nextInt();
           Boolean result = isMultiple(firstnumber, secondnumber);
            System.out.println("" + result );
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Do you wan to continue? Press y to continue or n to exit" );
            loop = input.next();
           }while(loop.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
   }

// creates method using the user input
public static Boolean isMultiple( int a, int b)
      {
          if(a==0 || b==0)
          {
              return false;
          }
          else
          {
              if(b % a ==0)
              {
                  return true;
              }
              else
              {
                  return false;
              }
          }

// returns e as the result of this method.
        } // end program
    } // end class
```

User input have been put in the loop. This program will accept the user input and check the values.